# Powershell Script to reset Local Administrator password

Tags: powershell

I have a script which is to reset local administrator password of remote machines and I have mentioned the host list in the script.But just would like is there any way, so that we can add line in my script, so that this will reset the administrator password of all machine which is there in a specific set of subnet(example :10.241.1.0 and 10.241.2.0)?

Can anyone help me with that ?

```
$computers = Get-Content -path C:\hosts.txt
$user = "Administrator"
$pass = "password1"

Foreach($computer in $computers)
{
 $user = [adsi]"WinNT://$computer/$user,user"
 $user.SetPassword($pass)
 $user.SetInfo()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily generate a subnet of IP's using the range operator (`a..b`).  I would define a function and then call it with the particular subnet:

```
Function Get-SubnetIps($subnet){ 1..254 | %{ $subnet + $_ } }
```

Example usage would be:

```
$computers = Get-SubnetIps "192.168.1."
$user = "Administrator"
$pass = "password1"

Foreach($computer in $computers)
{
    $user = [adsi]"WinNT://$computer/$user,user"
    $user.SetPassword($pass)
    $user.SetInfo()
}
```

You may run into problems if every IP is not reachable.  `try/catch` will save you if that should come to pass.  When writing these sorts of scripts, it can be [helpful to report progress](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/29/add-a-progress-bar-to-your-powershell-script/).

Comment: The following exception occurred while retrieving member "SetPassword": "The network path was not found.
"At line:4 char:5
The following exception occurred while retrieving member "SetInfo": "The network path was not found.
"At line:5 char:5

Comment: Like I said: "You may run into problems if every IP is not reachable. try/catch will save you if that should come to pass. When writing these sorts of scripts, it can be helpful to report progress."